# Not the desired out from a self-constructed function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

```
library('pracma')
q <-function(beta){
    beta[1] + 
    beta[3]*(
      3 *exp(1*beta[2])/(exp(1*beta[2])+exp(2*beta[2])) +
      4 *exp(2*beta[2])/(exp(1*beta[2])+exp(2*beta[2]))
      )
  
}
jacobian(q,c(1,1,1))

     [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 0.1966119 3.731059
```

Create a for loop for the exponential part generating the same results:

```
g <-function(beta) {
  j = 1:2
  sumeal <- sum(exp(j*beta[2]))
  eal <- c()
  for (i in j) {
    eal[i] <-(exp(i*beta[2]))/sumeal
  }
  beta[1]+beta[3]*(3*eal[1]+2*eal[2])
}

     [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 0.1966119 3.731059
```

Now I would like to generate this function for a set of values. So for example also for 5 and 6

```
q <-function(beta){
    beta[1] + 
    beta[3]*(
      5 *exp(1*beta[2])/(exp(1*beta[2])+exp(2*beta[2])) +
      6 *exp(2*beta[2])/(exp(1*beta[2])+exp(2*beta[2]))
      )
  
}
jacobian(q,c(1,1,1))

     [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 0.1966119 5.731059
```

The objective is to write the function with the for loop in such a manner that I get the following output

```
     [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 0.1966119 3.731059
[2,]    1 0.1966119 5.731059
```

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work

```
g <-function(beta) {
  j = 1:2
  sumeal <- sum(exp(j*beta[2]))
  eal <- c()
  for (i in j) {
    eal[i] <-(exp(i*beta[2]))/sumeal
  }
  xlag <- matrix(c(3,5,4,6), ncol = 2)
  ealx <- xlag * eal[col(xlag)] #2x2 matrix which multiplies the values by the exponential part
  beta[1]+beta[3]*(ealx) #probably where it goes wrong with the multiplication
}
jacobian(g,c(1,1,1))

     [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,]    1 -0.5898358 0.8068243
[2,]    1  0.9830597 3.6552929
[3,]    1 -0.7864477 1.0757657
[4,]    1  1.1796716 4.3863515
```

Which is not of the correct size and incorrect values

Comment: I don't see any difference in the first construct and the next except that 3, 4, changed to 5, 6

Comment: This one is different, the other one had a simple mistake which I figured out how to solve.  Indeed 3,4 is changed to 5,6 y However, what I would like to obtain is a function such that it outputs the case for 3,4 and 5,6 from 1 function. Instead of manually changing the 3,4 for 5,6.

Comment: Are you trying to change both parameters i.e. 3, 4 to 5, 6

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Where preferably the values 3,4,5 and 6 are obtained from a matrix

Comment: Your last code block is different from the others above.  Please check the solution posted

Comment: If you can update with expected output for last code block, would be easier to check

Comment: In the minimal case, you are doing `beta[1]+beta[3]*(3*eal[1]+2*eal[2])` but in your function you are passing 3, 4, and 5, 6 as matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the parameters, by adding 2 more

```
q <-function(beta, n1, n2 ){
    beta[1] + 
    beta[3]*(
      n1 *exp(1*beta[2])/(exp(1*beta[2])+exp(2*beta[2])) +
      n2 *exp(2*beta[2])/(exp(1*beta[2])+exp(2*beta[2]))
      )
  
}
```

Now, we do this either with `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(n1, n2) jacobian(q, c(1, 1, 1), 
     n1= n1, n2 = n2), c(3, 5), c(4, 6)))
```

-output

```
      [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 0.1966119 3.731059
[2,]    1 0.1966119 5.731059
```

---

Or a `for` loop

```
n1 <- c(3, 5)
n2 <- c(4, 6)

out <- c()
for(i in seq_along(n1)) {
   out <- rbind(out, jacobian(q, c(1, 1, 1), n1 = n1[i], n2 = n2[i]))
}
out
     [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 0.1966119 3.731059
[2,]    1 0.1966119 5.731059
```

---

For the 'g', we can use `rowSums`

```
g <-function(beta) {
  j = 1:2
  sumeal <- sum(exp(j*beta[2]))
  eal <- c()
  for (i in j) {
    eal[i] <-(exp(i*beta[2]))/sumeal
  }
  xlag <- matrix(c(3,5,4,6), ncol = 2)
   ealx <- rowSums(xlag * eal[col(xlag)])
  beta[1]+beta[3]*(ealx)
  
  } 

jacobian(g,c(1,1,1))
     [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 0.1966119 3.731059
[2,]    1 0.1966119 5.731059
```

Or may use `%*%`

```
g <-function(beta) {
  j = 1:2
  sumeal <- sum(exp(j*beta[2]))
  eal <- c()
  for (i in j) {
    eal[i] <-(exp(i*beta[2]))/sumeal
  }
  xlag <- matrix(c(3,5,4,6), ncol = 2)
   ealx <- xlag %*% eal
  beta[1]+beta[3]*(ealx)
  }
jacobian(g,c(1,1,1))
     [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 0.1966119 3.731059
[2,]    1 0.1966119 5.731059
```

Comment: This is indeed the desired output I would like. However, I would like the model to also be flexible for the exponential part. Which I in the original post constructed with a for-loop.  I am refering to the eal[i] part. Is there a way to implement this in your suggested solution?

Comment: @Wietze so you want the `g` instead of `q`.  Sorry, was confused my lot of functions in the post

Comment: @Wietze Are those same functions or is it different calculations.  What is the expected output in your last code block

Comment: @Wietze can you change the line to `ealx <- xlag * eal[col(xlag)]` in your code block

Comment: @Wietze I updatd the post.  By looking more clearly, there is a `+` missing, which can rectify with `rowSums`